# Retrieving the value of a Wicket text field when its form is submitted

Tags: java, wicket

Inside a `ModalWindow`, I have a panel that contains a text field. How can I use Wicket to retrieve the value of the field when the user submits the form that it is a part of?

Comment: What Version of Wicket? Ajax or no Ajax? If you work without Ajax, than wicket takes care of converting, validating and pushing the value in the model beloning to the textfield. If Ajax, use the appropriete member function of your textfield.

Comment: I believe the previous editor accidentally changed the meaning of your post with his edit, and I tried to fix it. Sorry if I was the one who got it wrong.

Comment: This may to be related to the other two questions the OP has asked recently: [accessing session value in wicket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090202/accessing-session-value-in-wicket) and [hide and show ajax button in wicket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113184/hide-and-show-ajax-button-in-wicket)

Answer (score 1):

One common way to save form values is to set up a `PropertyModel` ([Javadoc](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.4.17/wicket-1.4.17-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/wicket/model/PropertyModel.html)) relationship between the form component (in your case, the text field) and some variable in your Java code.

For example, if you're trying to get the name of a company's CEO, you might use

```
Company theCompany = new Company();
// ...
add(new TextField("ceoName", new PropertyModel(theCompany, "ceo")));
```

in your page class,

```
<input type="text" wicket:id="ceoName">
```

in your markup and

```
class Company {
    String ceo;
    // ...
```

elsewhere.

If you provide more information about what you're trying to do, I and others might be able to provide more specific/helpful answers.